# Organize table in SQL Server to remove NULL values and start from same level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to format table data in SQL Server.
Currently my table shows data as:-

[image]

I want to modify table data to show as:-

[image]

Please tell the query I need to make the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to query the data in that way, then simple aggregation should be enough.

```
select code,
    max(val1) as val1,
    max(val2) as val2,
    max(val3) as val3
from your_table
group by code;
```

If you want to modify data in your table i.e. update and delete rows to get the final result, one way is to use `MERGE`:

```
with cte as (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by code order by code) as seqnum,
        max(val1) over (partition by code) as max_val1,
        max(val2) over (partition by code) as max_val2,
        max(val3) over (partition by code) as max_val3
    from your_table t
)
merge into cte as t
using cte as s
on (
    t.code = s.code
    and t.seqnum = s.seqnum
    and t.seqnum = 1
)
when matched then update set 
    t.val1 = s.max_val1,
    t.val2 = s.max_val2,
    t.val3 = s.max_val3
when not matched by source then delete;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/OEG43414)